# Nested loop with indices

Tags: python, loops, nested

I'm trying to solve the following simplified problem. I have an array with data and two arrays with start and end indices stored. What I would like is to double the values of the dataset that fall between the indices (so between and including start[0], end[0] and start[1], end[1] etc). I tried a nested loop as follows:

```
data = np.array([0,1,2,8,4,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,8])
start = np.array([0,5,7])
end = np.array([3,6,9])

new_data = np.zeros(len(data))
for i in range(len(start)):
   for j in range(len(data)):
       if (j >= start[i]) & (j <= end[i]):
            new_data[j] = data[j]*2
       else:
            new_data[j] = data[j]
```

The result should be [0,2,4,16,4,10,12,10,8,10,6,7,8], and yet the code returns:
[ 0.  1.  2.  8.  4.  5.  6. 10.  8. 10.  6.  7.  8.]

Only the part between the last indices is correct. Any ideas why? And what if I want to triple the values not satisfying the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're repeatedly assigning to new_data, overwriting previous changes.

I.e.:

```
new_data[j] = data[j]*2 # won't work
data[j] = data[j]*2     # will work.
```

Comment: A very logical explanation. Thank you, this fixed the issue.

Comment: What if I want to triple the values that are not satistfying the if condition? How to adjust the else statement?

Comment: Maybe accept the answer then. 
Haha, also data[j]=data[j]*3

Comment: "else: data[j]:data[j]*3" does not work. That's why I asked :)

Comment: Hahah, yeh of course, good point, it's multiplying everything. You'd need to use enumerate in your current situation. 

But at that point, i'd use one of the zip solutions above.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `new_data` with `data` and remove the `else`.

**Edit:**
This should answer you, it's more efficient, since you're iterating through the whole array the number of intervals you have, and that will be slow for large inputs, but here you'll go through the array once.
And if you want to triple the other elements, a naive solution is to multiply `new_data` by 3 before the `for` loop, so put `new_data = np.copy(data)*3`.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([0,1,2,8,4,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,8])
start = np.array([0,5,7])
end = np.array([3,6,9])
new_data = np.copy(data)    # change to new_data = np.copy(data)*3 to triple other elements.

for i in range(len(start)):
    for j in range(start[i], end[i]+1):
        new_data[j] = data[j]*2
```

Another notice in your code is `(j >= start[i]) & (j <= end[i])`, this could be simplified to `start[i] <= j <= end[i]`, probably more fast.

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to triple the values that are not satistfying the if condition? How would I need to adjust the else statement?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using python's `zip` command in order to simultaneously unpack multiple lists.

Code explaination:
Since the datapoints which don't belong to any sublists remain the same, I used numpy's `copy` method to create a new copy of your original data. Then I muliplied your desired sublists by two.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([0, 1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
start = np.array([0, 5, 7])
end = np.array([3, 6, 9])

new_data = data.copy() #Not to mess up our original dataset.
for s, e in zip(start, end):
    new_data[s:e+1] *= 2 #Because it's an inclusive set.
```

Comment: Nice! This is the answer I wanted to writeup but considered was overkill to actual user issue, good work